# Problem to transpose multiple observations with conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot, transpose

I have this problem when creating a database from another one, this is the original database:

| Country | Code | Year1 | Year2 | Year3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Country1 | Code1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Country2 | Code2 | 11 | 22 | 33 |
| Country3 | Code3 | 111 | 222 | 333 |

and I need it to look like this:

| Country | Code | Year | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Country1 | Code1 | Year1 | 1 |
| Country1 | Code1 | Year2 | 11 |
| Country1 | Code1 | Year3 | 111 |
| Country2 | Code2 | Year1 | 2 |
| Country2 | Code2 | Year2 | 22 |
| Country2 | Code2 | Year3 | 222 |
| Country3 | Code3 | Year1 | 3 |
| Country3 | Code3 | Year2 | 33 |
| Country3 | Code3 | Year3 | 33 |

I find it difficult because I have 200 countries and 50 years, so transposing leads me to repeat many times the country and the years and match them with the value. I hope you can help me. Thank you very much :)

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_longer(mydf, starts_with("Year"), names_to = "Year")`